# Can I automate a TFS reverse integration merge

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, branching-and-merging

We have multiple stand-alone hybrid dev/test teams, each with their own environments where code is written and tested as a complete unit.  When an environment is in a tested deployable state, they merge from their main branch to an Integration branch.  We also have a true test environment where we can do full end-to-end testing of the entire ecosystem before moving to production.

Here's an abbreviated diagram of the structure:

[image]

Does TFS have an automate a process where any changes checked in to the _Pretest branch would be merged to the team branches?  I would prefer that if one team breaks what another team is doing, we break it in a dev environment and as early as possible.

(I know a big part of the answer is unit tests... we're working on it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automated process for merge on TFS because merge may contain conflicts. But you may use "tf.exe" utility with command merge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command?view=vsts

> tf merge branch2 branch1 /recursive

Comment: This is just a standard branch command though.  Most of our devs are using the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio to right click and merge as opposed to a command line.  They can do the same to manually merge new changes from _PreTest to their individual dev branches.  I can ask that they do it manually daily, or at a minimum, before they merge to _PreTest, but something more automated would be better.  Even if I could just get some kind of messaging that says that there's new code in _Pretest that hasn't been merged yet, I'd be happy.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your devs may do that manually or every morning through task scheduler with cmd file.